# Migration Axis2 to CXF -> multiple ports one service

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, cxf, apache-tomee

we found out that the WSDL stuff is not working anymore after a migration from Axis2 to CXF:

```
<wsdl:service name="WSService">
    <wsdl:port name=WSServiceSOAP11port_http" binding="ns:WSServiceSOAP11Binding">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/WSService"/>
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="WSServiceHttpport" binding="ns:WSServiceHttpBinding">
        <http:address location="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/WSService"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

In the Axis2 implementation the WSDL is delivered with WSService?wsdl

```
<wsdl:service name="WSService">
    <wsdl:port name=WSServiceSOAP11port_http" binding="ns:WSServiceSOAP11Binding">
        <soap:address location="http://server.com:8080/axis2/services/WSService.WSServiceSOAP11port_http/"/>
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name=WSServiceHttpport" binding="ns:WSServiceHttpBinding">
       <http:address location="http://server.com:8080/axis2/services/WSService.WSServiceHttpport/"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

In current implementation with CXF the answer is

```
    <wsdl:service name="WSService">
       <wsdl:port binding="tns:WSServiceSoapBinding" name="WSServiceSOAP11port_http">
          <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/WSService"/>
      </wsdl:port>
   </wsdl:service>
```

where the deployed war has still the same name axis2.

I wonder, I was not able to find a solution to bind the ports to the webservice.

The same WSDL is generated with wsdl2java. `wsdlsToGenerate = [["$wsdlDir/WSService.wsdl"]]`
But I can't generate the correct binding.

We use Jax-Ws but there was no success today:

```
@Stateless
@WebService(
        portName = "WSServiceSOAP11port_http",
        serviceName = "WSService",
        targetNamespace = "http://example.com/WSService/",
        endpointInterface = "com.example.WSService.IWSService")
public class WSService implements IWSService {
```

Does anybody have an idea how to generate the two ports defined in the WSDL to the webservice/SOAP address in the JakartEE context?

Thanks,
Markus